# Doubts in configuration of SQOOP

Tags: sqoop

### Scenario:

I have configured SQOOP on my PC. But I am facing some problem that,
when I go for bin/sqoop I get some error as:

### Error:

Exception in thread "main"

```
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:` 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getInstances(Ljava/lang/ 
String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/List; 

    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool.loadPlugins(SqoopTool.java:139) 
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:209) 
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:228) 
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:237)
```

### Question:

What could be the problem? I have also set the path of $HBASE_HOME and $ZOOKEEPER_HOME.
Please suggest me how can we do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls some one help me regarding this. As I am newbie to sqoop, I am facing many problems in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you the steps as I configured on my terminal.

1. Downloaded sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1 from the Cloudera archive.
2. Download mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 and copy the **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar** file to lib and bin directory of sqoop (for sqoop and mysql connection)
3. Copy all jars from lib to bin (optional)
4. Add 2 lines in .bash_profile file

   export SQOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/Desktop/Cloudera/sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1

   export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
5. Save it and just type sqoop help on terminal

It worked on my terminal. Post me the steps you followed .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-384

Try to downgrade to a different version of Sqoop.